# Перевести все автоматически добавленные Visual Studio комментарии на английский язык?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как перевести либо же удалить все автоматически добавленные Visual Studio комментарии на английский язык?

Comment: Как я понимаю, речь идет о комментариях к коду, которые был сгенерирован автоматически? Типа WinForms?

Comment: Да,вы абсолютно правы

Comment: Попробуйте изменить язык в меню VS >> Tool >> Option >> International Setting

Comment: Английского нет

Comment: @deced чтобы он там появился надо поставить английскую версию среды

Comment: Ладно,придётся тереть комментарии вручную,так быстрее будет...Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @deced в 17 студии их можно отключить так: Tools >> Options >> Text  Editor >> C/C++ >> Formatting >> Indentation >> Preserve indentation of comments

Comment: @deced не обязательно полностью переустанавливать. Запустите инсталлятор студии и добавьте нужный язык. Это значительно быстрее переустановки. Уже добавленные комментарии придется править руками